# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'evaluate' error with hyperas in keras

Tags: python, keras

I keep getting a 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'evaluate' error with the following code using hyperas and keras. Any help would be appreciated!

The error is **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'evaluate'**

This is my first keras and hyperas project.

```
#First keras program
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras import models
from keras import layers
from keras import optimizers
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from hyperas import optim
from hyperas.distributions import choice
from hyperopt import Trials, STATUS_OK, tpe
#Loading Data
#Train_images has shape (60000,28,28)
#Train_labels has shape (60000)
def data():
    (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
    train_images = train_images.reshape((60000, 28 * 28))
    train_images = train_images.astype('float32') / 255
    test_images = test_images.reshape((10000, 28 * 28))
    test_images = test_images.astype('float32') / 255
    train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels)
    test_labels = to_categorical(test_labels)
    return train_images,train_labels,test_images,test_labels

#Defining Network and adding Dense Layers
#Compiling Network
def create_model(train_images,train_labels,test_images,test_labels):

    network = models.Sequential()
    network.add(layers.Dense({{choice([256,512,1024])}}, activation='relu', input_shape=(28 * 28,)))
    network.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
    network.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
    network.fit(train_images,
                train_labels,
                validation_split=0.33,
                epochs=5,
                batch_size=128)

    score,acc = network.evaluate(train_images,train_labels,verbose=0)
    print('Test accuracy:',acc)
    out={'loss':-acc,'score':score,'status':STATUS_OK}
    return out

if __name__ == '__main__':
    best_run, best_model = optim.minimize(model=create_model,
                                          data=data,
                                          algo=tpe.suggest,
                                          max_evals=1,
                                          trials=Trials())
    x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = data()
    # mnist_model=create_model(x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test)
    print("Evaluation of best performing model:")
    print(best_model.evaluate(x_test, y_test,verbose=0))
    print("Best performing model chosen hyper-parameters:")
    print(best_run)
```

Here is the full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/anubhav/Desktop/Projects/chollet/keras_mnist_dense_hyperas.py", line 51, in <module>
    print(best_model.evaluate(x_test, y_test,verbose=0))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'evaluate'
```

Comment: You need to provide a complete traceback in order for the error message to make sense and we can match it with your code.

Comment: Got it. Just added the traceback. Thank you for looking at it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, seems like your`optim.minimize` function is not returning a model.

Looking into the [library](https://github.com/maxpumperla/hyperas/blob/master/hyperas/optim.py), I found that `best_model` by default `= None`, if you haven't put in valid `trials` then it would remain that way to the end. I don't have much knowledge above Keras so what hyperas does in `Trials()` is beyond my knowledge.

Check that function and see what it would output or if it needs any input to generate output etc.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running experiments in create_model() and then throwing the model away. If you return the models this may solve your problem. Try:

```
out={'loss':-acc,'score':score,'status':STATUS_OK, 'model': network}
```